# Retrieving SIM ID

Tags: android

After searching the API and no luck, mybe anyone know how  could I retrieve the SIM ID of the device?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code to get International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI No.) id and phone id (IMEI No.) and Sim No. programmatically

Before doing this also set the user permission in the manifest file  "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

```
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imsi = mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
    String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); 
    String simno = mTelephonyMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
    Log.v("", ""+imsi);
    Log.v("", ""+imei);
    Log.v("", ""+simno);
```

Comment: This is to get sim serial no. ,Actually I was trying this for my android app. Thanks for posting adamk

Comment: So which one is the **unique** identifier for SIM card/chip? `getSubscriberId()` or `getSimSerialNumber()`? I am confused about the difference between IMSI and SIM serial number.

Answer (score 3):

Frrom [wikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_Identity_Module#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29)

> The Id = **Issuer identification number**
>   (IIN) Maximum of seven digits: Major
>   industry identifier (MII), 2 digits,
>   89 for telecommunication purposes.
>   Country code, 1-3 digits, as defined
>   by ITU-T recommendation E.164. Issuer
>   identifier, 1-4 digits.

so the API is :

```
public String getSimCountryIso ()
public String getSimSerialNumber ()
public String getSubscriberId ()
```

Comment: Hi, I am using Motorola device|(I1) and I didnt get the right number with those methods, any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the IMSI (subscriber ID in the SIM), Use the [getSubscriberId method in the TelephonyManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId%28%29).

Comment: For some reason, I got different number then what it relay is in my test phone (Motorola I1), any idea why? thanks.

Comment: @rayman - How do you know the "real" SIM id? Do you have some other method for reading it from the SIM card?

Comment: How do I know? I dont.. I need a method to retrieve that.

Comment: @rayman - So how do you know the value it's returning if different from the real one?